# How to define event handle for master page control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

Code behind:

```
Menu masterpagemenu = (Menu)this.Master.FindControl("NavigationMenuAdmin");
masterpagemenu.MenuItemClick += new EventHandler(masterpagemenu_Click);
```

Giving error as:

```
 Cannot implicitly Convert type System.EventHandler to System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuEventHandler
```

Why this is so?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a type conversion error. It's telling you that you're assigning an event of the wrong type to `MenuItemClick`. `MenuItemClick` is expecting `MenuEventHandler`, so try this instead:

```
masterpagemenu.MenuItemClick += new MenuEventHandler(masterpagemenu_Click);
```

Comment: can we handle above event of master page control on content page using jquery??

Comment: @kls: That's a good question. You may want to ask it as a separate one here :)